# Mvc model fields regular expression null value

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, model, attributes

I am using the regular expression for the Password field. Includes alpha-numeric string and md5.

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
[RegularExpression(@"^(((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,20})|([0-9a-f]{32}))$")]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

And, I'd leave the field empty password. But ValidationMessage shows "This field is required."
message.Even if delete Required, it still gives the message.

Friends, how can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, could you please specify what language this is?

Comment: Asp.net MVC4 web application in c#

Comment: OK. No idea about that stuff, sorry. Adding that as tags _might_ make sense...

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Required attribute worked for me for server-side validation.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used asp.net, and know nothing about it. However, 10 seconds on google tells me:

Make it nullable ( `public string? Passsword { get; set; }` )

Comment: In MVC the type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'.